# Is it possible to 'populate' object_id references using PyMongo? Or is this a bad non no-sql approach?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, pydantic

I'm trying to make a simple restful API following [this useful guide](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/flask-python-mongodb/).

However, and this could be a terrible mistake (and not a good no-SQL approach), I want different objects to store references to other objects. For instance a team has an array of ObjectIDs, one for players and one for matches.

```
class Team(BaseModelExtended):
    id: Optional[PydanticObjectId] = Field(None, alias="_id")
    name: str
    players: List[PydanticObjectId] = []
    matches: List[PydanticObjectId] = []
    date_added: Optional[datetime]
```

I want to be able to look up the names of all players in the team by populating the ids in the array. I know this is possible with Mongoose, but I'm not sure it's possible in PyMongo. I can't find a populate method in the PyMongo docs. Also, it's beginning to dawn on my that this might be a bad approach?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pymongo` doesn't have a `populate` function. You will have to make an aggregation pipeline with a `$lookup` [stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), which is [referenced](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in the `populate()` doc

> MongoDB has the join-like $lookup aggregation operator in versions >= 3.2.

So, doing something such as:

```
team_collection.aggregate(
  [
    {"$match": {"_id": team_oid}},
    {"$lookup": 
      {
        "from": "player",
        "localField": "players", # Works with an array
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "playerd_data"
      }
    }
  ])
```

Note that you can use `$lookup` [with an array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-unwind-example).

As for your other question, that's a choice for you to make. But if you only have highly structured data such as these ones, a NoSQL solution might not be the best one.